# Insert span surround link text using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to surround text section of a link with a `<span>` tag. So that;

`<a class="button" href="#">Text</a>`

becomes

`<a class="button" href="#"><span>Text</span></a>`

I'd like to achieve this using only JavaScript, however, I am open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can we see what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is an answer. I feel this is easier to understand:

```js
let anchor = document.querySelector(".button");
let html = anchor.innerHTML;

anchor.innerHTML = "<span>" + html + "</span>";
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do exactly what you asked.

This will do the job for all your elements with class `button` in your document

```
<a class="button" href="#">Text</a>
<script>
document.getElementByClassName("button").innerHTML='<span>'+document.getElementById("link1").innerHTML+'</span>';
</script>
```

This will be good to use if you want to do this to a certain button.

```
<a id="link" class="button" href="#">Text</a>
<script>
document.getElementById("link").innerHTML='<span>'+document.getElementById("link1").innerHTML+'</span>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.button')
el.innerHTML = '<span>' + el.textContent + '</span>'
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Text</a>
```